# How to create optional parameters for own annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

Following is the annotation code

```
public @interface ColumnName {
   String value();
   String datatype();
 }
```

I would like to make `datatype` an optional parameter, for example

```
@ColumnName(value="password")
```

should be a valid code.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Seems like the first example in the [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) says it all ...

```
/**
 * Describes the Request-For-Enhancement(RFE) that led
 * to the presence of the annotated API element.
 */
public @interface RequestForEnhancement {
    int    id();
    String synopsis();
    String engineer() default "[unassigned]"; 
    String date()     default "[unimplemented]"; 
}
```

Comment: i only looked at the tutorials.ie why i couldnt find this.may i know the difference between unassigned and unimplemented

Comment: There is not difference. They're just String values. They could be "peter" and "paul".

Comment: And what if my params are `Class<?>`s?

Comment: In that case, Java's type system still applies. For example `Class<?> proxy() default Object.class`

Comment: Thanks! The official documentation may have the example, but this SO post was the top hit on my Goggle search so your response and the link are helpful!

Answer (score 41):

To make it optional you can assign it a default value like that:

```
public @interface ColumnName {
   String value();
   String datatype() default "String";
 }
```

Then it doesn't need to be specified when using the Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

For **custom types** you can do something like this

```
public @interface SomeAnnotation {

  Class<? extends SomeInterface> yourCustomType() default SomeNullInterface.class;
  
}

/**
 * Your custom type
 */
public interface SomeInterface {

}

/**
 * Your fake null value type
 */
public interface SomeNullInterface extends SomeInterface {

}
```

And somewhere in your code you can then check for null like this

```
if(!yourAnnotation.yourCustomType().isAssignableFrom(SomeNullInterface.class)){
  //your value is null
}
```